# Shape click opens external data tab

Tags: vba, visio, excel-external-data

I am trying to get my visio to be able to open a certain external data tab when a certain shape is clicked. I have found how to link the data from a specific row to a shape but not the other way around.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will help you [VISIO - highlight specific row in the data file when clicking on the corresponding shape in Visio.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/visio-highlight-specific-row-in-the-data-file-when/6fd62b22-850d-4e9c-a312-26302065b5ca)

Some of the highlights include: The way to gain access to that window is to loop through each of the `ActiveWindow.Windows`.  When you come across one that has the ID of `visWinIDExternalData` then you can control the `Window.SelectedDataRecordset` and `Window.SelectedDataRowID` properties.  The code left by the Microsoft MVP in that forum also includes how to get the DataRecordsetID and DataRowID from the selected shape thus enough data is available to provide the window with the selection that you desire.

Additional resources:

[Shape.GetLinkedDataRow Method (Visio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766409%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Shape.GetLinkedDataRecordsetIDs Method (Visio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765483%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Window.SelectedDataRecordset Property (Visio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767283%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Window.SelectedDataRowID Property (Visio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767377%28v=office.15%29.aspx)